# ActionLink/RouteLink not using specified actionName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink

On the *Index.cshtml* view of **EuroController** i have an *ActionLink* that i want to use the "IndexByYear" action of Euro controller:

`@Html.ActionLink("Year 2006", "IndexByYear","Euro", new { id = "", year = 2006 }, null)`

But the problem is that it goes to the Index() method, even though it's everything set on **RouteConfig**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Euro",
     url: "{controller}/{year}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Euro", action = "IndexByYear", year = DateTime.Now.Year, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Here's the **EuroController**:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
     ...
    }
    public ActionResult IndexByYear(int? id, int year)
    {
     ...
    }
```

Also this don't work, as it also goes to Index() method:

`@Html.RouteLink("Ano 2006","Euro",new { id = "", year = 2006 },null)`

If i manually navigate to *domain/Euro/2016/1*, then it uses the correct route. Seems like with no parameters it goes through the Default route.

My question is, why does the ActionLink don't use the IndexByYear as specified, or the RouteLink use the specified default (Euro) route?

Comment: Swap the order of your routes.

Comment: If i do that, **domain/** shows the Index() of EuroController, instead of HomeController.

Comment: That is because you've replaced the catch-all route with your modified version. Change `Euro` back to `Home`. If you only want that specific route to match, create a copy that replaces the `{controller}` placeholder with `euro`.

Comment: So what you're saying is i should change defaults: new { controller = "Euro"....} **TO** defaults: new { controller = "Home" ....} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want **just** the EuroController to have a "special" routing, you would want to do something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Euro",
     url: "euro/{year}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Euro", action = "IndexByYear", year = DateTime.Now.Year, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultNoController",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { isMethodInHomeController = new RootRouteConstraint<Controllers.HomeController>() }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Where the constraint is defined like so:

```
public class RootRouteConstraint<T> : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var rootMethodNames = typeof(T).GetMethods().Select(x => x.Name.ToLower());
        return rootMethodNames.Contains(values["action"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

This will match

- `domain/euro/1` to the Index action on EuroController
- `domain/euro/2008/1` to the IndexByYear action on EuroController
- `domain/` to the Index action on HomeController
- `domain/about` to the About action on HomeController
- `domain/someothercontroller` to the Index action on whatever other controllers you define

You may want to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx and https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs